# Batch Script Game was not expected at this time

Tags: batch-file

I'm a new batch programmer and am creating a batch "start menu". I'm using the following text and it's saying "X" was not expected at this time. X was 1, game, text, and other things. I can't figure it out. HELP! I'm running XP SP3 and using the command prompt. Also, if anyone spots any other mistakes please inform me. e-mail me at superzemus@hotmail.com

```
cls
@echo off
echo Welcome to the Start Menu!

echo.
echo Press ctrl-z to exit. Press G to play Adventure. Press T to enter Text Editor. 
pause
set Game= %gme% 
set Text= %txt%

IF select Game goto gme
IF select Text goto txt

:txt
echo You have chosen to enter the Text editor.
pause
start edit

:gme
echo You have chosen to play Adventure.
pause
start C:\Adventure.exe
```

Comment: interesting to use batch script as game Start Menu. Why not a tiny Windows Form program?

Comment: Which command processor? I've not seen SELECT in a command file. Why not comment out @echo off and run the script again. It will echo each line and you can see where it's failing. Or post the out put here

Comment: I want to get experience using batches (Shivan Raptor) and I don't know what comment out means (Preet Sangha). Sorry, but I've only been doing this for 64 hours now.

Answer (score 1):

What you want here is probably either `set /p`:

```
set /p choice=Press ctrl-z to exit. Press G to play Adventure. Press T to enter Text Editor.
```

and then compare as follows:

```
if /i %choice%==G goto Game
if /i %choice%==T goto Text
goto :eof
```

Or use `choice` which doesn't require you to press Return:

```
choice /m "Press Q to exit. Press G to play Adventure. Press T to enter Text Editor." /c GTQ /n

if errorlevel 3 goto :eof
if errorlevel 2 goto Text
if errorlevel 1 goto Game
goto :eof
```

There is also another problem with your code: You should exit the batch file after starting the editor to avoid starting the game too:

```
:Text
start edit
goto :eof

:Game
rem That's a horrible place to put something
start C:\Adventure.exe
goto :eof
```